# how to increment the columns dynamically for an excel sheet in php

Tags: php, excel

here is the code am using

```
$key1 = $this->uri->segment(3);
          $letter1 = "B";
   for($i=0;$i<$key1;$i++){
//$letter1++;
$letter=$letter1++;
echo($letter);
$s = $letter+'3';
echo($s);}
```

for this am getting output as B3C3D3.....

when am using like this

```
$key1 = $this->uri->segment(3);
$letter1 = "B";
for($i=0;$i<$key1;$i++){
    //$letter1++;
    $letter=$letter1++;
    echo($letter);
    $s = $letter+'3';
    echo($s);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($s, 'State');
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($letter)->setWidth(20);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($s)->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($s)->getFont()->setSize(10);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($s)->getFont()->setBold(true);
    $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($s)->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER);
}
```

am not getting excel sheet and also am getting output as only B3

what was going wrong here can someone help me please thanks.

Comment: these values are not taking into that excel sheet code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put the word "State" into columns B3, C3 and D3, try this:

```
<?php
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once '../Classes/PHPExcel.php';

$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

$letter = "B";
for($i=0; $i<3; $i++){
    $s = $letter . '3';
    echo($s);
    $sheet->setCellValue($s, 'State');
    $letter++;
}

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save("test.xlsx");
```

This will create test.xlsx file with appropriate data. I wrote the skeleton code, I think you can add styles yourself.